# Turbolinks 5 javascript not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-5, turbolinks-5

I found out that my javascript code would not work when certain links where clicked.

When i set a breakpoint, the following js was not triggered after certain links

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', ready);
```

This is the link where js works

```
<%= link_to companies_path, method: :get, id: "Companies" do %>
```

This is the link where js does not work

```
<%= link_to "New Campaign", new_campaign_path, method: :get %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link with the attribute `method: :get` would have a `data-method="get"` in his html

```
<a id="Companies" data-method="get" href="/companies">
```

While the other one would not have this data-method.

```
<a class="btn btn-success btn-fill" data-method="get" href="/campaigns/new">New Campaign</a>
```

I solved the issue by explicitly declaring the data-method with the following syntax.

```
<%= link_to "New Campaign", new_campaign_path, method: :get %>
```

I did not find any discussion on StackOverflow explaining this, but please attach the links if you find them.

The issue is solved

Thanks
Best Regards
Fabrizio